# Is it possible to run a unix script using oozie outside hadoop cluster?

Tags: oozie

We have written a unix batch script and it is hosted on a unix server outside Hadoop Cluster. So is it possible to run that script via oozie?

If it is possible then how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

What is the script doing? If the script just needs to run regulary you can as well use a cronjob or something like that.

Besides this, Oozie has a action for SSH Actions on Remote hosts. 
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_SshActionExtension.html

Maybe you can work something out with that by loging into the remotehost, run the script, wait for completetion and work on from there.